# Riemannian generalization/adaption of the Hubbard–Stratonovich transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, fourier-transform, diffusion, sigma-models

I'd like to write the [Hubbard–Stratonovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hubbard%E2%80%93Stratonovich_transformation&redirect=no) (HS) transformation of  a scalar function on a Riemannian manifold. This transformation is quite simple in Euclidean space. One can consider it as a [Fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a Gaussian function:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{a}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)  f(x)~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a}\right)   f(x+y), \qquad a~>~0.
$$ 
However, my question is can whether one apply HS transformation to a scalar function on a compact Riemannian manifold? If yes, then how?

I couldn't understand how to define the Fourier transform on a compact Riemannian manifold. It seems to me the Fourier transform is defined by the [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) but it goes a little technical and I'm not familiar with.. Nevertheless, I guess one can write the Hubbard-Stratonovich transform:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{a}{2}\Delta\right)  f({x})~=~ (2\pi a)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\int d^n{y}\sqrt {g(y)}\exp\left(-\frac{{y}^2}{2a}\right) f({x+y})~,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the [Laplace–Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator). In addition, I read that the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform#Generalizations) can be defined on any Riemannian manifold, but it doesn't make sense to me, I couldn't find any proper references and don't know how to write this transform.

Context:

My real problem involves the free energy of a harmonic oscillator on a Riemannian manifold which leads to an trasformation similar to the HS transformation. Indeed, potential energy of harmonic oscillator is $U=\frac{1}{2}kd(y,y_0)^2$ which $k$ is a constant, $d(y,y_0)$ is distance. I simply assumed that $d(y, 0)=y^2$. Under what conditions on the Riemannian manifold $M$ can I write a transformation similar to to the one mentioned above? As far as I understand, one can define the FT on a Riemannian manifold when it is either a Lie group or a symmetric space.

Comment: Perhaps math.SE is a better place for this question?

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423479/11127